# PowerPivot Hide second column label but keep grand total

Tags: hide, powerpivot

I've set up a powerpivot with the the following:

[Exmple here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWRoN.png)

It's producing an additional column (blue columns Productivity Index2) that I don't want to see. But I want to keep the total column (Total Productivity Index2) along with everything else.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyIOU.png)

Is there a way to remove the blue columns yet keep the total?

I tried HideColumns in powerpivot but it also hid the totals.

Note - ignore totals. This is just an example of the real data.

Comment: I think the answer might be to create another power query  with the summary data. Then switch to power pivot and create a relationship to the main table. Will try this tomorrow.